# Running multiple commands in a if statement

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to modify the below [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) script to do two things on an if statement:

```
if ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName -ieq "DumpCreds")
{
    $ExeArgs = "privilege::debug"

}
elseif ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName -ieq "DumpCerts")
{
    $ExeArgs = "crypto::cng crypto::capi `"crypto::certificates /export`" `"crypto::certificates /export /systemstore:CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE`" exit"
}
else
{
    $ExeArgs = $Command
}`
```

The line where it reads - `$exeargs = "privilege::debug"`, I need run that and I also need to run - `$ExeArgs = "sekurlsa::logonpasswords"`  The privilege one needs to run first followed by the logonpasswords one.

How do I run 2 commands in 1 if statement in a [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) script?

Comment: You want to assign a value to `$ExeArgs` twice in one if block?  What would that achieve?

Comment: Yes, well the priv argument is a requirement that needs to be set before I can run the logonpasswords one.  Is there a way to do it?

Comment: `$ExeArgs = ' "privilege::debug" "sekurlsa::logonpasswords" '`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `if` statement has no restriction about how much commands you execute in it, so just execute it...

```
if ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName -ieq "DumpCreds")
{
    $ExeArgs = "privilege::debug"
    $ExeArgs = "sekurlsa::logonpasswords"    
}
elseif ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName -ieq "DumpCerts")
{
    $ExeArgs = "crypto::cng crypto::capi `"crypto::certificates /export`" `"crypto::certificates /export /systemstore:CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE`" exit"
}
else
{
    $ExeArgs = $Command
}
```